# Improve Excecution Time of For Loop by Replacing it with lapply command

Tags: r, for-loop, optimization, parallel-processing, lapply

Here I am working on optimization of R-code , As we all know Most time consuming is `for loop` , I am trying to replace it with lapply and experiment to reduce the Execution time.

[image: Time Line for every processing syntax: Profvis]
As one can see in the image the time required to excute the for loop is taking 40 Msec , here the task is to how one can minimize the execution time for For Loop here By using lapply . `How to replace this code of for loop with Lapply` so that we can optimize the processing speed of code afficiently. To dentify the time required for every line of code Library Profvis is used.
I have tried using the lapply , I am facing issue in implementation

```
library(profvis)
profvis({
rm(list = ls())
# Creating Dummy data 
row_id <- 100
No_of_level <- 4
spliz <- paste("c(","TRUE,",paste(rep("FALSE",(row_id-1)),collapse=","),")")
d <- as.data.frame(matrix(,nrow = row_id*No_of_level ,ncol=2))
names(d) <- c("Tag","y_pred")
d$Tag <-  cumsum(rep(eval(parse(text=spliz)),4))
d$y_pred <- sample(3:4, row_id*No_of_level, rep = TRUE)
d$y_pred <- paste("L",d$y_pred,sep="")
#### ------------------------------------

# How to replce Below For Loop codes to lapply and get the result in the variable.     
    v <- data.frame();i=0
    for (i in (1:max(d$Tag))){
      #i=4
      s <- filter(d , Tag == i)
s$y_pred <- as.character(s$y_pred)
      temp = 0
      for(i in 1:nrow(s))
      s$R2[i] <- ifelse(s$y_pred[i] == "L3", temp <- temp + 1, 0)
      s$seq <- seq_along(1:nrow(s))
      s$Aoc <- (1-(s$R2/s$seq))*100
      s$Aoc1 <- (s$R2/s$seq)
      v <- rbind(v,s)
  }

})
```

**Expected :** Improve the execution time as of now for above For Loop code , execution time is 40 msec , if we try with lapply may be we can bring Processing time from 40 msec to  10 msec  or less then that.

Comment: I don't think that `lapply` is much faster than a for-loop. It is basically just a wrapper around the loop. If you can express it with `apply` (without the l) things may really speed up.

Comment: Why create `spliz` as a collapsed string and use `eval(parse())`? If you don't need `spliz` as a string anywhere else, you could do `spliz <- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE, (row_id-1)))` and `d$Tag <-  cumsum(rep(spliz,4))`

Comment: I have a guide 'Parallelize a For-Loop by Rewriting it as an Lapply Call' (https://www.jottr.org/2019/01/11/parallelize-a-for-loop-by-rewriting-it-as-an-lapply-call/) on how to achieve this - hopefully that'll help you.

Comment: @zx8754 I have already created a dummy data ...And yes I agree I have taken a different method to create dummy data . But our main goal is `how to make for loop faster instead can we use lapply ?

Comment: @LAP that chunk of code is to create a categorical variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what your expected output is, but something like this should work:

```
v <- do.call(rbind, 
             lapply(split(d, d$Tag), function(s){
               res <- s
               res$R2 <- ifelse(as.character(res$y_pred) == "L3", 
                                cumsum(as.character(res$y_pred) == "L3")), 0)
               res$seq <- seq_along(1:nrow(res))
               re$Aoc <- (1-(res$R2/res$seq))*100
               res$Aoc1 <- (res$R2/res$seq)
               #return
               res
             }))
```

Comment: For ifelse statement we have to add `temp <- temp + 1` .  how we can do that . the value in R2 should keep on change in a sequence instead it is only assigning 1 to R2, if ifelse statement is True

Comment: `v1 <- do.call(rbind, 
             lapply(split(d, d$Tag), function(s){
               s$y_pred <- as.character(s$y_pred)
               temp = 0
               res <- s
               res$R2 <- ifelse(as.character(res$y_pred) == "L3", temp <- temp + 1, 0)
               #res$R2 <- ifelse(s$y_pred == "L3", temp <- temp + 1, 0)
               res$seq <- seq_along(1:nrow(res))
               res$Aoc <- (1-(res$R2/res$seq))*100
               res$Aoc1 <- (res$R2/res$seq)
               res
             }))`

Comment: I tried putting `temp = 0` inside the function , but that is not adding `temp <- temp + 1` in ifelse statement .

Comment: @Harvey maybe change ifelse to cumsum: `res$R2 <- cumsum(as.character(res$y_pred) == "L3"))`

Comment: it worked , but lets suppose I want to do counting of some event . in that how should we assign a variable , because I tried assigning temp = 0 and did temp <- temp + 1 , but it wasn't working

Comment: @Harvey you can get this from v object?